# How to dual-boot Ubuntu on a separate drive?

Tags: installation, dual-boot

I want to install Ubuntu on a separate drive with Windows 7 64-bit on the primary drive.

How do I do this?

Comment: While you were typing this question you must have observed questions which were resembles your's and most of them were answered. Please go through those you will find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

First, read this please:
[https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot "WindowsDualBoot"](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot)